# REGEX in Pentaho to clean a join column in my data

Tags: regex, pentaho

I have been struggling with a certain column in my data where the source data is dirty and i cant find joins because of this.

So What I am trying to do is:

1. Select the column [website_reference_number] among others
2. REGEX to review [website_reference_number] according to certain specs
3. Then I need to trim that data so that there are no in-consistencies left so that my joins will be clean

In example

```
if [website_reference_number] = "CC-DE-109"                >>> Leave it like that

if [website_reference_number] = "CC-DE-109-Duplicate"      >>> change to CC-DE-109

if [website_reference_number] = "CC-DE-109 Duplicate"      >>> change to CC-DE-109

if [website_reference_number] = "CC-DE-109-Duplicate-Duplic" >>> change to CC-DE-109
```

So the rules are in human terms `{Any 2 Letters}-{Any 2 Letters}-{AnyAmountOfNumbers}`

Comment: Like this: [`[a-z]{2}-[a-z]{2}-\d{3}`](https://regex101.com/r/tL7xE2/1) ? Mind the case insensitive modifier.

Comment: @Jan I guess you should use `[A-Z]` instead of `[a-z]` *(based on OP's examples)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this pattern:

```
/([A-Z]{2})-([A-Z]{2})-([0-9]+).*/
```

#### [Online Demo](https://regex101.com/r/kX3bC3/1)